# using glmnet with future

Tags: r, multiprocessing, glmnet

On windows, I have difficulties using `library(doparallel)` which seems to crash after a few `glmnet` calls

So I am trying to use the `future` package (https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future) with `glmnet` but I am unsure what is the best way to proceed here.

Here is a simple example (non parallelized)

```
X = matrix(rnorm(1e4 * 200), 1e4, 200)
Y = rnorm(1e4)
system.time(cv.glmnet(X, Y))
user  system elapsed 
3.42    0.22    3.67
```

How can I use futures to use all of my 4 cores (on my local machine - no distributed cluster as in [executing glmnet in parallel in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698435/executing-glmnet-in-parallel-in-r))

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need furrr? And not just doFuture as in the link you provided? Or is the title of the question incorrect?

Comment: yes thank you, i meant future

Comment: @phiver do you have an idea then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. At least the usertime is a lot lower, but system time increased due to parallel overhead.

```
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()
plan(multiprocess, workers = 4L)

system.time(cv.glmnet(X, Y, parallel = TRUE))

user  system elapsed 
0.46    0.17    5.59 

versus

system.time(cv.glmnet(X, Y))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.33    0.05    2.39
```